# Objective-C Xcode: How to 'contain' a UITouch drag event to a certain area (two objects to act separate)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, touch

I'm a bit new to programming, but am creating an app for iOS in which there are going to be up to four objects that need to be moved separate from each other. So I need to know how to create 4 different areas on the screen that the user can touch and swipe to drag each object.
Sorry if this question was asked before! I didn't find the answer, but I may have just been searching the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Gesture recognizer:**
You can verify the touch area in the selector. 
Create 4 separate gesture recognizer on 4 objects.
And in each's handler, check for the touch location, verify it and respond accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I personally haven't written out the code for this yet, just doing little tutorials and practice runs with it and such. There's plenty of examples of this out there, so I think it's safe to say this is a good solution. Thank you!